# api call to django logout is not logging user out

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and trying to implement login/logout functionality. I am using React as my frontend. even after making Axios request to /auth/logout/ I can still see the user as logged in on my backend. And it's giving no error.
[here I can see the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BewhK.png)

these are the rest framework settings

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

    ]
}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    url(r'users/', UserListView.as_view(), name='userListView'),

]
```

logoutView.js

```
class LogoutView extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount (){

        Axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/myaccount/auth/logout/", {withCredentials: true})

        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            })

    }

    render(){
        return(
                <Logout />
            )
    }
}
```

this is the response object I got after logout call

```
Object
config: {url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/myaccount/auth/logout/", method: "post", data: "{"withCredentials":true}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: {detail: "Successfully logged out."}
headers: {content-length: "37", content-type: "application/json"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
```